# Доступ к элементам потомка из предка

Tags: javascript

В программе на javascript трудности с наследованием - родитель должен вроде бы пользоваться полями/методами потомка - но делать он это может через this. А у меня для избежания сложностей с вызовами хэндлеров вместо this используется self... Зато через него не получается достать поле/метод потомка.

Нижеприведённый код демонстрирует проблему. Извиняюсь - не удаётся нормально воспользоваться гуглом т.к. ключевые слова (parent, child, this, virtual и т.п.) слишком заюзаны.

```
function A() {
    var self = this;
    self.mao = function() {
       //alert(self.lao); // this fails
       alert(this.lao); // this works
    }; // mao
} // A

function B() {
    var self = this;
    self.lao = "lao";
} // B

B.prototype = new A();

var a = new B();
a.mao();
setTimeout(a.mao, 2000); // here is the problem with "this"
```

Можно ли в подобном случае как-то удобно обходить эту проблему?

Comment: Объясните мне простом смертному - какой смысл self???

Comment: Он хранит тот this, который был при создании объекта. Т.к. при вызове функции в качестве хэндлера (например с помощью setTimeout) this будет указывать вовсе не на сам объект а на окно, например... %)

Comment: ясно, експирименты велосипедостроительства xDDD

Comment: Ну дык если б кто-то оставил хотя бы толковую ссылку на толковую доку вместо зубоскальства, то и экспериментов, и велосипедов и глупых вопросов было бы меньше. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

В вашей ситуации `A::self` - существует в единственном экземпляре ( вы его создали только для прототипа, и нигде более )...

Если вы очень хотите:

```
function B() {
    var self = this;
    self.lao = "lao";

    A.apply( self );
}
```

P.S: Наследование сделано не корректно ( `B.prototype = new A();` )

Comment: Спасибо, пойду разбираться по поводу примечания PS.

Answer (score 1):

JS лучше писать следующим образом:

```
var WebObject = {
     param1: 1,

     test : function (a){
          console.log(a); 
     },
     start: function () {
          WebObject.test(WebObject.param);     
     } 
}
```

пример, в котором необходима конструкция : "var self = this;"

```
var WebObject = {
     param1: "mypdage.html",
     resp: "",
     test : function (a){
           var self = this, param = WebObject.param1;
           jQuery.ajax({
                 url: self.param, //Получаем param из родительского объекта
                 type: "POST",
                 success: function(data) {
                        WebObject.resp = data;  //Суем дату в нашу переменную resp
                 } 
           }); 
     },
     start: function () {
          WebObject.test(WebObject.param);     
     } 
}
```

Т.е. в self ты оставляешь ссылку на родителя.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){a.mao.apply(a)}, 2000);
```

Comment: (то ли у меня ответ не прицепляется, то ли не знаю что - осмелюсь повториться)
Этот способ мне не нравится тем, что тот, кто пользуется классом/объектом, должен всё время иметь в виду что он не может использовать 
setTimeout(a.mao, 2000); нормально, из-за того что разработчик класса/объекта (я) не придумал как решить проблему поэлегантнее...

Comment: доступ в методу предка только через применение метода.
в таком случае полагаю Вам надо было определять метод через A.prototype.method = function(){...}

Comment: Спасибо, попытаюсь осознать этот момент!

Comment: http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/inheritance#vyzov-roditelskih-metodov
http://shamansir.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/

Comment: @RodionGork, Всё уже написано: `A.apply( self );` и будет работать... Будьте по внимательнее

Comment: извините, но не будет... что делает в Вашем случае A.apply( self ) ?

Comment: @timka_s Да, всё правильно, спасибо - немного подумав я понял Ваш пример и стал им пользоваться. Правда нашёл случай когда и этого недостаточно: если метод перекрыт в потомке, и из него пытается вызваться аналогичный метод предка с помощью Child.prototype.method.apply(self) - то метод предка (прототипа) будет иметь self != this... У прототипа же вообще один self на все инстансы потомков - об этом я не подумал...